# What happens when a switch sends a frame to another switch?

Tags: switch, mac-address

When a host sends a frame to a switch, the switch maps the frame's source MAC address to the port it was received on. Then if a frame with that MAC address as the destination is received, it knows to send that frame on that port. And if it doesn't know what port to send a frame on, it sends it on all ports.

What about if a frame is received from another switch? What if switch A sends switch B 2 frames, both with different source MAC addresses? How does switch B handle that situation?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 7):

Switch B associates both MAC addresess with the port it was received on.  A port can have multiple MAC addresses mapped to it.